# Promise and onsubmit

Tags: javascript, scope, promise, es6-promise

I'm building a form with front-end password hashing:

```
<form action='login.php' method='post' onsubmit='hash(this)'>
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br>
    <input type='hidden' name='shapassword'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

My hash function use SubtleCrypto Web API. It call `digest()` function, which returns a Promise:

```
function hash(form) {
    const buff = new TextEncoder().encode(form.password.value);
    p1 = crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', buff).then(param => {
        form.shapassword.value = new TextDecoder().decode(param);
    });
}
```

However, shapassword isn't passed to script which recive data from form. I suppose `hash()` returns before the Promise is fulfilled, am I right? How to prevent leaving `hash()` function or access to `form` object from `then` function?

Comment: `form.shapassword.value = new TextDecoder().decode(hash);` This line doesn't make much sense - you're passing `decode` the *function you're currently in*? `hash` isn't a hash, `hash` is a function. (try to name your variables properly to avoid confusion) Did you mean to pass it `param` instead, or does it actually work when passing it `hash`?

Comment: Of course you're right, it's `decode(param)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `preventDefault` to prevent the form from submitting by user click, and wait for the `Promise` to resolve before actually submitting the form. It's also good practice to attach listeners with Javascript instead of inline handlers:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  getEncodedText(form);
});

function do(form) {
  const buff = new TextEncoder().encode(form.password.value);
  crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', buff).then(param => {
    form.shapassword.value = new TextDecoder().decode(param);
    form.submit();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `hash` function return `false`, then once the promise has resolved, call `.submit()`

```
function hash(form) {
    const buff = new TextEncoder().encode(form.password.value);
    p1 = crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', buff).then(param => {
        form.shapassword.value = new TextDecoder().decode(hash);
        form.submit();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @charlietfl Nope, [`.submit()` does not trigger events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

Comment: @Bergi my bad...retract my statemnt

Comment: Notice you'll need to use `onsubmit='return hash(this)'` for the `false` solution. I recommend using `event.preventDefault()` instead